# In Elixir, how can I take a list of Strings ["3", "4", "-2", "20", "false"] as params for a function def linear(m,c,min,max,_)

Tags: int, boolean, elixir, stringtokenizer

I have an Elixir function such as:

`def linear(m,c,min,max,_) when someCondition do something end`

I have a list of Strings: `["3", "4", "-2", "20", "false"]`

How can I transform this list into `[3,4,-2,20,false]` so that I can do:

`desiredFormat |> linear()` or similar.

Using `String.to_atom(head)` would work for `"false"` and using:

`String.to_integer(head)` would work for the the strings that are integers but I cannot find a solution for a 'mixed' list like this.

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "derive" the type to convert each element in the list to as they're all just strings. Since it looks like you know the size and order of the list beforehand, you can simply do a little more work with something like this:

```
def parse_list([m, c, min, max, bool]) do
  [String.to_integer(m),
   String.to_integer(c),
   String.to_integer(min),
   String.to_integer(max),
   String.to_existing_atom(bool)]
end

parse_list(["3", "4", "-2", "20", "false"])
#=> [3, 4, -2, 20, false]
```

Now, if you want to use these arguments directly in `linear/5`, you can use [`apply/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/2):

```
apply(&linear/5, parse_list(my_list))
```

Btw, just to mention this: another solution exists, and it's to parse each element in the string to infer its type. If your list always contains just integers and booleans, writing a supersimple parser is straightforward:

```
def parse_elem("true"),  do: true
def parse_elem("false"), do: false
def parse_elem(int),     do: String.to_integer(int)

apply(&linear/5, Enum.map(my_list, &parse_elem/1)
```

Complexity increases if you need to have other types (e.g., floats) in the list.

Comment: Very nice solution.  Just what I was looking for thanks.